# YII dataProvider relation CDbCriteria

Tags: php, yii, render, criteria, dataprovider

I have a problem regarding the use of CDbCriteria in a controller index action. I have 2 classes: event and attendee.
the class event has many attendee, and i want my event index action to render only the list of events of which the current loggedin user is an attendee...

```
  $criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(                    
                            'order'=>'event_date desc',
                            'with'   => array('attendees'=>array('alias'=>'attend')),
                            'condition'=>'attend.uid = ' . Yii::app()->user->id,
                    ));
  $dataProviderAtt=new CActiveDataProvider('Event',
                    array(
                    'criteria'  => $criteria,
                            )
            );

  $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderAtt,
    ));
```

this does not work in DB with the message:
    CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'user'

my relations in attendee class are set like this:

`public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'YumProfile', 'uid', 'alias'=>'user'),
        );
    }`

I tried to change the defaultscope in attendee model and define multiple aliases:

```
   public function defaultScope()
{
  static $counter = 0;
   return array(
         'with' => array('user'=>array('alias'=>'user'.($counter++))),
         //'with' => 'user',
      'order' => 'score DESC',
     );
 }
```

but it does not seem to fix the issue and I then have more errors. Is my criteria correctly set?
Thx guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for

```
'on' => 'attend.uid = ' . Yii::app()->user->id,
```

as in your relation to the user

```
function relations()
{
    return array(
        'user' => array(
            self::BELONGS_TO,
            'attendees',
            '',
            'on' => 'attendees.uid = ' . Yii::app()->user->id,
        ),
    );
}
```